# Passing Alpine JS value to Livewire component

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I was wondering if there's a way to retrieve an Alpine JS variable and passing it to a Livewire component.
Something like:

```
<template x-for="(something, index) in array" :key="something">
   @livewire("component", ["variable" => something])
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Livewire [`@entangle()`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js) feature to share property state between alpine and Livewire.

Define your alpine variable like below:

```html
<div x-data="{ something: @entangle('something') }">
    
</div>
```

And in your livewire component like this

`public $something = null;`

Now whenever you change your component variable value it will be updated on the alpine variable and vice versa